# Google Play console app (AAB) not working

Tags: apk, android-app-bundle

Google Play console app (AAB) not working

We are working on a react native app and have completed development. We have compiled the app as APK and installed it on our phones, with no problems. We are now at the stage of testing where we need to upload it to Google play console, and have our internal testers use the app.

The problem we are facing is that once we compile the app as AAB, which is required by google play, the app seems to fail by giving a white blanks screen after login in. So we basically upload the AAB file, share it with our testers, and the feedback is the screen goes blank after login in to the app, please note this does not happen with the APK version.

Does anyone have a solution to this or have experienced a similar issue on google play console?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.